# Given a non-abelian group $G$ with $|G|=p^3$ and $p$ prime, how do I show that $|Z(G)|=p$?

Tags: group-theory

Given a non-abelian group $G$ with $|G|=p^3$ and $p$ prime, how do I show that $|Z(G)|=p$? $Z(G)$ is as always center of $G$.

It is easy to see that $|Z(G)|\in\{p, p^2\}$, but how do I exclude $p^2$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $G$ is non-abelian, already edited. thanks

Comment: There's a standard exercise to show that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

If $\frac{G}{\rm{Z}(G)}$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.